# cakephp select multiple strings from a string in a column

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm using cakePHP 2.3 to build an application with a restaurant database. Now, the person before me has saved restaurant details in a table called 'locations' which has a row for cuisine which has multiple values in one column, like 1 location can have chinese, indian, korean etc.

If the column has values stored like this "north indian,chinese,mughlai",I want that non adjacent cuisines should be searchable too...like if i receive "'north indian' 'mughlai'" in the posted data, it should still show even though there's chinese in between. Basically is there a command to select multiple partial values from a string in the column?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$saved="north indian,chinese,mughlai";

$search="north indian, mughlai";

foreach(explode(",",$search) as $keyword)
{
    $keyword=trim($keyword);
    if(stristr($saved,$keyword)!==false)
    {
        echo "Match Found for $keyword <br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response..how can I use it in CakePHP though? I'm using an array (conditions)

Comment: String::tokenize() + a IN sql search would save you some lines of code :D

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a conditions array entry for each cuisine using LIKE as the comparison operator. *This builds on Hanky Panky's example*

```
$conditions = array();

foreach (explode(",", $search) as $keyword)
{
  $keyword=trim($keyword);
  $conditions[] = "columnname LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'";
}
```

Then your find is:

```
$this->Location->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I think he wants to find all restaurant tha have mughlai cuisine OR the ones that have chinese cuisine. So: `$conditions['OR'][] = "cuisine LIKE '%$keyword%'";`